# Second (unwanted) state change (Angular ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular ui-router to manage my app's state. I had a very simple configuration, that looked like this:

```
  $stateProvider.state({
    url: "/home",
    name: "home",
    sticky: true,
    views: {
      header: { component: "header" },
      main: { component: "home" }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: "modal",
    data: {},
    views: {
      modalcontent: { component: "modalcontent" }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: "modal.login",
    data: {},
    views: {
      modalheader: { component: "modalheader" },
      modalmain: { component: "login" }
    }
  });
```

Calling `$state.go("modal.login")` from my home controller would work just fine.

After analyzing some further requisites that my app had, I realised that I need to implement a global state in order to satisfy those needs, so I changed the config this way:

```
  $stateProvider.state({
    name: "app",
    abstract: true,
    url: "/:language",
    data: {},
    views: {
      app: { component: "app" }
    },
    params: {
      language: {
        dynamic: true
      }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    url: "/home",
    name: "app.home",
    sticky: true,
    views: {
      header: { component: "header" },
      main: { component: "home" }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: "app.modal",
    data: {},
    views: {
      modalcontent: { component: "modalcontent" }
    }
  });

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: "app.modal.login",
    data: {},
    views: {
      modalheader: { component: "modalheader" },
      modalmain: { component: "login" }
    }
  });
```

This, apparently small, change caused a side effect: now I can't go to the `app.modal.login` state.

I turned on transitions debugging and I found this:

```
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.modal.login, function (trans) {
            trans['_treeChanges'] = _this._calculateStickyTreeChanges(trans);
        }
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.modal.login, function addCoreResolvables(trans)
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.modal.login, function updateGlobalState(trans) {
    var globals = trans.router.globals;
    var transitionSuccessful = function () {
        globals.successfulTransitions.enqueue(trans);
        globals.$curre...
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onBefore context: app.modal.login, function ignoredHook(trans)
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onBefore context: app.modal.login, function invalidTransitionHook(trans)
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
VM286778:133 Transition #1-0: Started  -> "Transition#1( 'app.home'{"language":"en-US"} -> 'app.modal.login'{"language":"en-US"} )"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function eagerResolvePath(trans) {
    return new resolveContext_1.ResolveContext(trans.treeChanges().to)
        .resolvePath("EAGER", trans)
        .then(common_1.noop);
}
Transition #1-0:         Resolving [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (EAGER)
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function (trans) {
    trans.promise.then(function (state) {
      body().removeClass(function (index, className) {
        return (className.match(/(^|\s)state-\S+/g) || []).join("");
      });
  ...
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function () {
    modal().css("display", "block");
  }
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function () {
    main().removeClass("nobg");
  }
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function () {
    main().removeClass("mobilenobg");
  }
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.modal.login, function (trans) {
    if (!$state.current.name.includes("app.modal")) {
      currentState = _angular2.default.copy($state.current);
    }
    trans.promise.then(function () {
      $state.current...
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onEnter context: app.modal, function lazyResolveState(trans, state) {
    return new resolveContext_1.ResolveContext(trans.treeChanges().to)
        .subContext(state.$$state())
        .resolvePath("LAZY", trans)
        .th...
Transition #1-0:         Resolving [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (LAZY)
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onEnter context: app.modal.login, function lazyResolveState(trans, state) {
    return new resolveContext_1.ResolveContext(trans.treeChanges().to)
        .subContext(state.$$state())
        .resolvePath("LAZY", trans)
        .th...
Transition #1-0:         Resolving [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (LAZY)
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onFinish context: app.modal.login, function loadEnteringViews(transition) {
    var $q = coreservices_1.services.$q;
    var enteringViews = transition.views("entering");
    if (!enteringViews.length)
        return;
    return $q....
VIEWCONFIG: Loaded [View#3 from 'app.modal' state]: target ui-view: 'modalcontent@app'
VIEWCONFIG: Loaded [View#4 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalheader@app.modal'
VIEWCONFIG: Loaded [View#5 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalmain@app.modal'
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onFinish context: app.modal.login, function () {
    $timeout(function () {
      initTooltips();
    });
  }
Transition #1-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
VM286778:176 Transition #1-0: <- Success  "Transition#1( 'app.home'{"language":"en-US"} -> 'app.modal.login'{"language":"en-US"} )", final state: app.modal.login
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function transitionSuccessful() {
        globals.successfulTransitions.enqueue(trans);
        globals.$current = trans.$to();
        globals.current = globals.$current.self;
        common_1.cop...
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function updateUrl(transition) {
    var options = transition.options();
    var $state = transition.router.stateService;
    var $urlRouter = transition.router.urlRouter;
    // Dont update the ur...
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function () {
            tc.exiting.forEach(__webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__uirouter_core__["removeFrom"])(_this._inactives));
            tc.entering.forEach(__webpack_require_...
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function activateViews(transition) {
    var enteringViews = transition.views("entering");
    var exitingViews = transition.views("exiting");
    if (!enteringViews.length && !exitingViews.length)...
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [View#3 from 'app.modal' state]: target ui-view: 'modalcontent@app'
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [View#4 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalheader@app.modal'
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [View#5 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalmain@app.modal'
(index)ui-view fqnstate: view name0"ng1:app""app: app (ng1)"1"ng1:app.footer"undefined2"ng1:app.header""app.home: header (ng1)"3"ng1:app.main""app.home: main (ng1)"4"ng1:app.modalcontent""app.modal: modalcontent (ng1)"Array(5)
ui-view: Updating                       [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)] with ViewConfig from context='app.app.modal'
ui-view: Destroying scope               [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)]
ui-view: Animate out                    [ui-view#undefined undefined:undefined (undefined@(none))]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)] with: <modalcontent></modalcontent>
ui-view: Linking                        [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)] with: 
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)]
(index)ui-view fqnstate: view name0"ng1:app""app: app (ng1)"1"ng1:app.footer"undefined2"ng1:app.header""app.home: header (ng1)"3"ng1:app.main""app.home: main (ng1)"4"ng1:app.modalcontent""app.modal: modalcontent (ng1)"5"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader""app.modal.login: modalheader (ng1)"Array(6)
ui-view: Updating                       [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)] with ViewConfig from context='app.app.modal.app.modal.login'
ui-view: Destroying scope               [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)]
ui-view: Animate out                    [ui-view#undefined undefined:undefined (undefined@(none))]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)] with: <modalheader></modalheader>
ui-view: Linking                        [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)] with: 
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)]
(index)ui-view fqnstate: view name0"ng1:app""app: app (ng1)"1"ng1:app.footer"undefined2"ng1:app.header""app.home: header (ng1)"3"ng1:app.main""app.home: main (ng1)"4"ng1:app.modalcontent""app.modal: modalcontent (ng1)"5"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader""app.modal.login: modalheader (ng1)"6"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain""app.modal.login: modalmain (ng1)"Array(7)
ui-view: Updating                       [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)] with ViewConfig from context='app.app.modal.app.modal.login'
ui-view: Destroying scope               [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)]
ui-view: Animate out                    [ui-view#undefined undefined:undefined (undefined@(none))]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)] with: <login></login>
ui-view: Linking                        [ui-view#7 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter (modalfooter@app.modal)]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#7 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter (modalfooter@app.modal)] with: 
VIEWCONFIG: -> Registering [ui-view#7 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter (modalfooter@app.modal)]
(index)ui-view fqnstate: view name0"ng1:app""app: app (ng1)"1"ng1:app.footer"undefined2"ng1:app.header""app.home: header (ng1)"3"ng1:app.main""app.home: main (ng1)"4"ng1:app.modalcontent""app.modal: modalcontent (ng1)"5"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter"undefined6"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader""app.modal.login: modalheader (ng1)"7"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain""app.modal.login: modalmain (ng1)"Array(8)
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.home, function (trans) {
            trans['_treeChanges'] = _this._calculateStickyTreeChanges(trans);
        }
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.home, function addCoreResolvables(trans)
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.home, function updateGlobalState(trans) {
    var globals = trans.router.globals;
    var transitionSuccessful = function () {
        globals.successfulTransitions.enqueue(trans);
        globals.$curre...
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onBefore context: app.home, function ignoredHook(trans)
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onBefore context: app.home, function invalidTransitionHook(trans)
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
VM286778:133 Transition #2-0: Started  -> "Transition#2( 'app.modal.login'{"language":"en-US"} -> 'app.home'{"language":"en-US"} )"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.home, function eagerResolvePath(trans) {
    return new resolveContext_1.ResolveContext(trans.treeChanges().to)
        .resolvePath("EAGER", trans)
        .then(common_1.noop);
}
Transition #2-0:         Resolving [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (EAGER)
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.home, function (trans) {
    trans.promise.then(function (state) {
      body().removeClass(function (index, className) {
        return (className.match(/(^|\s)state-\S+/g) || []).join("");
      });
  ...
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.home, function () {
    modal().css("display", "none");
  }
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.home, function () {
    main().removeClass("nobg");
  }
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onStart context: app.home, function () {
    main().removeClass("mobilenobg");
  }
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onFinish context: app.home, function loadEnteringViews(transition) {
    var $q = coreservices_1.services.$q;
    var enteringViews = transition.views("entering");
    if (!enteringViews.length)
        return;
    return $q....
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onFinish context: app.home, function () {
    $timeout(function () {
      initTooltips();
    });
  }
Transition #2-0:   <- Hook returned: "undefined"
VM286778:176 Transition #2-0: <- Success  "Transition#2( 'app.modal.login'{"language":"en-US"} -> 'app.home'{"language":"en-US"} )", final state: app.home
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function transitionSuccessful() {
        globals.successfulTransitions.enqueue(trans);
        globals.$current = trans.$to();
        globals.current = globals.$current.self;
        common_1.cop...
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function updateUrl(transition) {
    var options = transition.options();
    var $state = transition.router.stateService;
    var $urlRouter = transition.router.urlRouter;
    // Dont update the ur...
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function () {
            tc.exiting.forEach(__webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__uirouter_core__["removeFrom"])(_this._inactives));
            tc.entering.forEach(__webpack_require_...
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function activateViews(transition) {
    var enteringViews = transition.views("entering");
    var exitingViews = transition.views("exiting");
    if (!enteringViews.length && !exitingViews.length)...
VIEWCONFIG: <- Removing [View#3 from 'app.modal' state]: target ui-view: 'modalcontent@app'
VIEWCONFIG: <- Removing [View#4 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalheader@app.modal'
VIEWCONFIG: <- Removing [View#5 from 'app.modal.login' state]: target ui-view: 'modalmain@app.modal'
(index)ui-view fqnstate: view name0"ng1:app""app: app (ng1)"1"ng1:app.footer"undefined2"ng1:app.header""app.home: header (ng1)"3"ng1:app.main""app.home: main (ng1)"4"ng1:app.modalcontent"undefined5"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter"undefined6"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader"undefined7"ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain"undefinedArray(8)
ui-view: Updating                       [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)] with ViewConfig from context='undefined'
ui-view: Removing (previous) el         ui-view (defunct)
ui-view: Destroying scope               [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)]
ui-view: Destroying/Unregistering       [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)]
VIEWCONFIG: <- Deregistering [ui-view#5 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalheader (modalheader@app.modal)]
ui-view: Destroying/Unregistering       [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)]
VIEWCONFIG: <- Deregistering [ui-view#6 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalmain (modalmain@app.modal)]
ui-view: Destroying/Unregistering       [ui-view#7 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter (modalfooter@app.modal)]
VIEWCONFIG: <- Deregistering [ui-view#7 ng1:app.modalcontent.modalfooter (modalfooter@app.modal)]
ui-view: Animate out                    [ui-view#undefined undefined:undefined (undefined@(none))]
ui-view: Fill                           [ui-view#4 ng1:app.modalcontent (modalcontent@app)] with: 
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.home, function update()
```

Then I call the `$state.go()` method, angular ui-router triggers 2 transactions.
Extract of the important bit of the log:

```
Transition #1-0:   Hook -> onSuccess context: app.modal.login, function update()
Transition #2-0:   Hook -> onCreate context: app.home, function (trans) {
        trans['_treeChanges'] = _this._calculateStickyTreeChanges(trans);
    }
```

If I understand correctly, ui-router managed to successfully switch to my `modal.login` state, but then for some reason it switched back to the `home` state.

After a lot of debugging I found that if I pass the options `{location: false}`, this "bug?" won't happen anymore.

I'd like to know why is the `location: false` making that difference. Why my code worked before adding the global state, but it won't work now, after adding the global state?

Edit: I'm adding more findings I just made.

If I add an `url: "/login"` to my `app.modal.login` state, everything starts working again. I could easily let is be like that, but I want to find out what exactly is going on in ui-router (or maybe my code?) and fix it, instead of blindly applying workarounds.

Comment: You should be changing `$state.go("modal.login")` to `$state.go("app.modal.login")`

Comment: Err, yes, sorry, that is just a typo in my question.

Comment: You can actually see that the state I'm calling is `app.modal.login` in the log I attached.